# MS SQL table with GUID All Zeros

Tags: sql-server, guid

I have inherited a web application in which one of the back end MS SQL table has a field with:

Allow Nulls = No, DataType = uniqueidentifier, DefaultValue = newid(), Condensed Data = Type uniqueidentifier

Of the many thousand rows some have all zeros for the GUID. It does not appear to be legacy data as some have recent create dates.

How is it that SQL server does not put a proper GUID in that field when the app creates a new record?

EDIT: the EF Context for this field has this:

```
entity.Property(e => e.ThreadId).HasDefaultValueSql("newid()");
```

Comment: Maybe the app itself is inserting zero Guids insert of omitting the column on insert? With the information you're giving out, you won't get much more than wild guesses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uniqueidentifier data type does not mean that it will be unique. If you generate `NEWID()` then it generates unique id but again there is always a probability that same id may be generated.

For 0's

```
insert into t values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
insert into t values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
insert into t values (newid());
```

statements are valid. If your uid column is not primary key or has unique index on it, dublicate keys can be added to the table.

---

If you add check constraint to your table you can restrict and also identify the root cause of the problem

> ```
> create table t (
>   id uniqueidentifier unique
>   CONSTRAINT CHK_uid CHECK (id != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
> insert into t values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
> insert into t values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
> insert into t values (newid());
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_uid". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_80c5a5fe96ab4e73ac5dafbb2256025d", table "dbo.t", column 'id'.
> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 2
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_uid". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_80c5a5fe96ab4e73ac5dafbb2256025d", table "dbo.t", column 'id'.
> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 3
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_uid". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_80c5a5fe96ab4e73ac5dafbb2256025d", table "dbo.t", column 'id'.
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 1
> The statement has been terminated.
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 2
> The statement has been terminated.
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 3
> The statement has been terminated.
> ```

> ```
> select * from t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | id                                   |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | ddeb79f6-dc0f-4c6a-a065-2083d39a78c1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=184c06f229fc81396a6b5f677c6f8cb4)*

Comment: I must admit I'm a bit light on my understanding of constraints. I thought SQL made them for me when I set it to PK, Identity, etc. When I view the constraints on the table via RT click, Script Constraint as Create to New Query Window I see: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTableName] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ThreadId]

Comment: If you have PK, you don't need unique constraint however second constraint for 0s is still valid. The default value is used when no value is provided in insert. if I provide guid explicitly default value won't work

Comment: The table has a PK but this is not it. Looks like original developer wanted a single "comments" table to hold all comments across multiple tables/parts of the app. Every table that allows comments has a ThreadID (uniqueidentifier) The comments table keep a running thread for various parts using this ID. None of the other tables have zeros for guids at all. This one does, but in turn if it has all zeros it won't save comments because the comments table itself won't allow the all zeros to be entered into it. Sorry if this is confusing...I am. Thanks for help so far.

Comment: Can I add that constraint of not allowing '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' after the fact? I'd think yes but have not figured it out yet.

Comment: yes you can. `ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_uid CHECK (id != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')` but first you need to remove 0 uids

Answer (score 2):

If the SQL column is nullable, then the problem is in your C# code. Make sure the POCO classes use a nullable Guid as well. Also make sure you initialize the property when creating new instances. The C# default for a non-nullable Guid is an all-zero Guid. If the problem only exists with old data, the code may already have been fixed.

Comment: If you have a property like `public int GUID { get; set; }` and you never explicitly set it, its default will be 0 (comes from `default(int)`).

Comment: Allow Nulls is set to "No" on the table. While I have not been able to use the web UI to create a record with all zeros somewhere in the app it must be happening because I have entries with all zeros less than a week ago and no changes to the app's code in several weeks.

Comment: why dont you create unique constraint and check constraint on table?